# Select top 3 by element in JSON arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, json, hive, hiveql

The source data is

```
user_id video_interest
1 [{"category":"a","score":1},{"category":"b","score":2},{"category":"c","score":3},{"category":"d","score":4}]
2 [{"category":"e","score":1},{"category":"f","score":2},{"category":"g","score":-3}]
```

The output is

```
user_id video_interest_top3
1 [{"category":"d","score":4},{"category":"c","score":3},{"category":"b","score":2}]
2 [{"category":"f","score":2},{"category":"e","score":1}]
```

I need to filter score>0, and then select each user_id's top3 video_interest in descending order of score

Comment: in descending order shouldn't it be [{"category":"d","score":4}, {"category":"c","score":3}, {"category":"b","score":2}] ?

Comment: If you have sql-like access (like the *sql* tag let think) you could: `select * from <the table that maps your data> where score > 0`

Comment: @DDS score is in JSON format, you don't directly filter it.

Comment: Then why the SQL tag in the question?

Comment: @DDS video_interest is Array(JSON) type, so score is in a JSON object. You can see answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode JSON array, extract score, calculate max score per user (if necessary to order final output by score desc) and row_number by score to filter top 3, collect array again and concatenate it to STRING if necessary. See comments in the code. I added sorting arrays and the whole output, because it was initially not clear what exactly should be sorted: arrays or final output, remove max_score sorting if you do not need it.

Demo:

```
with mytable as (
select stack(2,  
1,'[{"category":"a","score":1},{"category":"b","score":2},{"category":"c","score":3},{"category":"d","score":4}]',
2,'[{"category":"e","score":1},{"category":"f","score":2},{"category":"g","score":-3}]'
) as (user_id,video_interest)
)

select --collect array and convert to JSON string
      user_id, max_score, concat('[',concat_ws(',',collect_list(category_score)),']') as video_interest
from
(
select user_id, category_score, max_score, score
from
(  
select --extract score, filter and sort
      user_id, vi.category_score, get_json_object(vi.category_score, '$.score') as score,
      row_number() over(partition by user_id order by get_json_object(vi.category_score, '$.score') desc) rn, 
      max(get_json_object(vi.category_score, '$.score')) over (partition by user_id) max_score
from
(--prepare for exploding array
select user_id, regexp_replace(regexp_replace(video_interest,'\\[|\\]',''), --remove []
                          '\\},\\{', '},,,{') as video_interest --replace , between array elements with ,,, to split
  from mytable
)s 
--split and explode
lateral view outer explode(split(video_interest,',,,')) vi as category_score
where get_json_object(vi.category_score, '$.score')>0
)s
where rn<=3 --filter top 3
distribute by user_id sort by score desc --Sort collection, remove if not necessary
)s
group by user_id, max_score
order by max_score desc --Sorting users by max_score desc, remove if not necessary
```

Result:

```
user_id max_score   video_interest
1       4           [{"category":"d","score":4},{"category":"c","score":3},{"category":"b","score":2}]
2       2           [{"category":"f","score":2},{"category":"e","score":1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I explode video_interest and make its category and score a single field.
Second, I use row_number() function to partition by user_id order by score(descending), then make each line be marked with their order in the group and filter order<=3
In the end, I use collect_list() to simply collect them as a list, because they were ordered when using row_number

```
select  user_id,
            collect_list(pos) as first_video_interest_top3
from    (
            select  user_id,
                    category,
                    score,
                    pos,
                    row_number() over(
                    partition by
                                user_id
                    order by
                                score desc
                    ) rNum
            from    (
                        select  user_id,
                                pos.category,
                                pos.score,
                                pos
                        from    myData
                        lateral view explode(video_interest) e as pos
                        ) t1
            where   score > 0
            ) t2
where   rNum <= 3
group by
            user_id
```